# Strogatz Exercise 8.5.3: Logistic equation and Poincarè maps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I am going through  [Strogatz's Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos](http://users.uoa.gr/~pjioannou/nonlin/Strogatz,%20S.%20H.%20-%20Nonlinear%20Dynamics%20And%20Chaos.pdf) and am stuck on one exercise from chapter 8 (exercise 8.5.3).

The first part of the problem says:

> Consider the logistic equation $\dot{N} = r N (N - N/K(t))$, where the carrying capacity is positive, smooth and T-periodic in t.
>
> a) Using a Poincaré map argument like that in the text, show that the system has at least one stable limit cycle of period T, contained in the strip $K_{min} \leq N \leq K_{max}$

My problem, I am afraid, lays in the base interpretation of the task.

I am expecting a 2D system, and instead I can only see one differential equation and one extra function ($F(t)$), for which I can't extrapolate any information about the derivative. I am baseically not able to draw the phase plane or sketch the vector field.

I am quite lost on how to start this exercise, but I would like to work on it. 
Does anyone have any ideas on how to interpret it?